# Parse IOS deleting all objects wherekey = objectID

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is there an easy way to delete all objects within a particular class (i.e. messages) which satisfy a particular condition, such as "UserID" = user, so that all of the rows within my message class associated with a particular user will be deleted?

Comment: You will need to elaborate further, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: What particular class are you using?  Sample code will help us help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messages"];
 [query whereKey:@"UserID" equalTo:@"user"];
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
 if (!error) {
     // The find succeeded.
     NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
     // Do something with the found objects
     for (PFObject *object in objects) {
         [object deleteInBackground];
     }
 } else {
     // Log details of the failure
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
 }
}];
```

**Update**

replace

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
    [object deleteInBackground];
}
```

with

```
[PFObject deleteAllInBackground:objects];
```

thanks mikewoz for the update.

Comment: Is there a more effective way to do this so that you don't have to launch a query to find the objects?

Comment: this seems query intensive

Comment: This is a very sought-after functionality among the community, but Parse has yet to implement it. The solution @Akhilrajtr offers is quite bandwidth-intensive if there are many objects. To alleviate that, you could create a cloud code function to handle it all in the backend.

Comment: Instead of using [object deleteInBackground] in a for loop, you should use [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:objects] to do it all in one request. More info on this call here: http://blog.parse.com/2013/07/22/deleting-multiple-objects-in-one-api-request/

Answer (score 0):

This helped me finally figure out how to delete all related pointer objects of a deleted object while using Parse and the local store.

Hope this saves someone a few hours.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Student", function(request) {

  // after delete a student find the associated sessions and remove
  var query = new Parse.Query("Session");

    var userPointer = {
      __type: 'Pointer',
      className: 'Student',
      objectId: request.object.id
    }

  query.equalTo("studentOwner", userPointer);

  query.find().then(function(studentSessions) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(studentSessions);
  }).then(function(success) {
    // The related sessions were deleted
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error deleting related sessions " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
  });
});
```